# Convert String to Clob in Java

Tags: java, sql, string, clob

I have a situation where I need to make Clob object from String.
The problem is I can't have ConnectionManager in that method.

I need to some utility like

```
 public Clob getClob(String data){

 }
```

Can any one tell me how can I make this.

I have oralce.sql.CLOB also. however it requires Connection to create object.

Comment: Why "can't [you] have ConnectionManager"? Could you use [`LobCreator`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/LobCreator.html)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this :

```
OracleConnection conn;  // initialize this first

CLOB clob = conn.createClob();

public Clob getClob(String data){

    return clob.setString(position, data);
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Those who are still looking for an alternate answer, a Clob object could be created without the need for a connection object as shown below.

```
Clob myClob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob(stringData.toCharArray());
```

Comment: Exactly what i am looking for ;-)

Comment: In my case I've returned `clob` from a *java stored function* but got this error - *ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected a return value that is an instance of a user defined Java class convertible to an Oracle type got an object that could not be converted*

Comment: Hibernate has a utlity too in case you want to use for CLOB and BLOB.
**Hibernate.createClob(yourJavaString)**
For BLOB 
**Hibernate.createBlob(yourJavaString.getBytes())**

Answer (score 11):

Throws warning: Clob not initialized.

You need an OracleConnection to create a Clob, using the Oracle Database.

```
OracleConnection conn;  // initialize this first

Clob myClob = conn.createClob();



private OracleConnection conn = null;
public void setConnection( OracleConnection conn )
{
    this.conn = conn;
}

void setClob( String cookie ) throws SQLException
{
    Clob myClob = conn.createClob();
    myClob.setString( 1, cookie);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to initialize the OracleConnection mentioned in the other answers here 
  and if you're doing this for a java stored procedure 
  and the connection is to the database where the procedure is stored, 
then the Connection can be initialized like this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");
```

and this import is needed:

```
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection;
```

Answer (score 1):

On my side, I use

```
Clob generateProxy(String string)
```

From

```
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.ClobProxy;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using spring boot and you only have a JdbcTemplate obj you can get an Oracle connection using:

```
private JdbcTemplate  jdbcTemplate;   // or NamedParameterJdbcTemplate 
Clob myClob = this.jdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection().createClob();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an opportunity to create a `[N]Clob` without a Connection you can use `NonContextualLobCreator` from the Hibernate project. Following example shows the create of an `NCLob` using a string

```
String xml = "my blob content";
NClob clob = NonContextualLobCreator.INSTANCE.createNClob(xml);
entity.setXmlclob);
```

Available from at least Hibernate 4.2 (maybe earlier).